# What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{\sqrt{n}}}{2^{n}}=? $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{\sqrt{n}}}{2^{n}}$$

I assume it's equal to $0$, but can't find a way to prove it.

I don't even know where to start..

Comment: Maybe if you change your expression using this:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\ln\left(\dfrac{n^\sqrt{n}}{2^n}\right)}$$

Comment: Duplicate: [What is the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{\sqrt{n}}}{2^n}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/63774/85969)

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{n^{\sqrt{n}}}{2^n} =\left(\dfrac{n}{2^\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n} \leq (\dfrac{1}{2})^\sqrt{n} \to 0$$

for $n$ large, since $\dfrac{n}{2^\sqrt{n}} \to 0$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{n^{\sqrt n}}{2^n}=\dfrac{\Big(2^{~\log_2n}\Big)^{\sqrt n}}{2^n}=2^{\big(\sqrt n~\log_2n\big)-n}.~$ Can you take it from here ? :-)